# Is it against license to publish Oracle and SQL Server performance test?

Tags: sql-server, performance, oracle, geospatial, database

I would like to make a performance test on spatial index in Oracle and SQL Server. I would like to include it in my Master of Science work. Is it against dbms's license to publish that kind of results ?

Maybe someone have already met that kind of problem ? I am not keen on digging through boring license stuff ;).

Comment: As far as I know you are not allowed to publish performance results for Oracle. But I can't find a reference right now.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name seriously? That is the silliest thing I have ever heard.

Comment: @njk If you're so sensitive about your reputation and competition you can do "silly" things like that.

Comment: I'd guess that since the OP didn't even know about DeWitt clauses, that maybe they shouldn't be writing a thesis on database benchmarking. DeWitt had a huge legal battle with Oracle way back in the and now works for microsoft. It is REALLY difficult to benchmark to the companies standards.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [standard license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html) you agree to when you download software from the Oracle Technology Network (OTN) does state that you're not allowed to disclose benchmarks.

```
You may not: 
<<list of things you cannot do>>
- disclose results of any program benchmark tests without our prior consent.
```

Microsoft's licenses (such as an [older SQL Server 7.0 license](http://contracts.onecle.com/aristotle-international/microsoft-eula.shtml)) generally have similar terms

> Performance or Benchmark Testing. You
>              may not disclose the results of any benchmark test of either the
>              Server Software or Client Software for Microsoft SQL Server, Microsoft
>              Exchange Server, or Microsoft Proxy Server to any third party without
>              Microsoft's prior written approval.

Most other large companies put similar terms in their license agreements.  Whether those license terms are actually enforcable as a matter of law in your case (particularly where this is an academic exercise) and whether either company would ever seriously consider suing over the publication of a Masters thesis is something that you would need to discuss with your university's legal department (and/or the legal department of whoever owns the licenses for the software that you're using).  As  a practical matter, I would think it's extraordinarily unlikely that either company would ever seriously consider suing a masters student with no money over unfavorable benchmark results.  Bloggers and conference presenters publish benchmark results all the time in forums that are much more likely to attract (or repel) potential customers and aren't sued.

Comment: I think that DeWitt Clause is to prevent false or innacurate bench-marking on imperfect systems. http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/the-devil-s-in-the-dewitt-clause

Comment: @FlavorScape - The most benign reading is the desire to prevent inaccurate benchmarks (though arguing about what is an "accurate" benchmark gets very contentious particularly when the workload or parameters happen to be optimized for one systems architecture).  If there was widespread compliance with the terms, though, vendors would certainly quash unflattering benchmarks or it would take so long for the vendor to vet the benchmark that it would be out of date before it could be published.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can license block a valid research paper. That's like Ford saying you can't verify its emissions claims. Gag orders like that on products/services are not generally legal, even if the terms say you agree to it. You could get sued out the ass for slander or libel though if there are flaws in either your experimentation methods or research analysis.

**It is REALLY difficult to benchmark to the companies standards in such a way that you won't get sued.**

Here's a paper on Oracle technology already. http://www.iisocialcom.org/conference/passat2012/PASSATProceedings/data/4578b119.pdf

"I am not keen on digging through boring license stuff" Well maybe you should be keen if you're afraid of getting sued.

Here's an oracle license from July. Quick glance, i see no restriction. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/license.112/e10594.pdf

Unless you state the specific technology down to the version or link to the license/terms of use, we cannot specifically say.

Here is an interesting read on the "gag" policies, but it's from 2007.
http://genellebelmas.com/documents/Belmas-Larson-Clicking%20away.pdf

Notable in the conclusion:
First Amendment jurisprudence provides considerable support to
the concept of a right to hear. Using the First Amendment to attack
gagwrap clauses directly would require that state action be found
first. Even without state action, however, the First Amendment provides a significant public policy basis upon which gagwrap clauses
might be found to be unenforceable. It remains to be seen how this
public policy rationale will work with the Restatement of Contracts
framework when evaluating gagwrap clauses.

Comment: Is that applicable for "Oracle DB servers"? because it says "Oracle VM (Virtual Machine) server"..

Comment: never said anything was applicable to anything. if OP wants specifics, they need to name the specific technology.

Comment: And the specific technology is "Oracle Database Server" (I believe). I asked the question because you said `Here's a paper on Oracle technology "already".` [This](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96630/sdo_index_query.htm) may be close to what he's referring to.

Comment: "Oracle Database is available in five editions, each suitable for different development 
and deployment scenarios. Oracle also offers several database options, packs, and 
other products that enhance the capabilities of Oracle Database for specific purposes"

Comment: Now we're on the same page. Its "Oracle Database Server" not "Oracle Virtual Machine Server".

Comment: I'm arguing that you can't put that in a license, i don't care what the tech is.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could if you are using 'Oracle Database Express Edition' for the purpose. But I guess it would be clever to have a quick consultation with an attorney with the Licensing document of Express edition.

Comment: I don't think gag orders hold up in court. That's like the cases where doctors were forcing patients to sign waivers saying they couldn't review them in the future. Those documents did not hold up legally.

Comment: I am no attorney and can't speak to that. Unless you want a big corp to burn down your house (:P which they won't anyways), I would review this with an attorney (but only if I am that worried).